# NoMethodError in Answers#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error when I go to `/questions/1/answers/new` route in my project.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42IfQ.png)

It says that I am trying to call some function which does not exist, but I am not calling any functions at all.

Here is `new.html.erb` for that form:

```
<h1>Write answer to question: <%= @question.title %></h1>

<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is `answers_controller.rb`:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.new
end

def create 
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    @answer.user = current_user
    @answer.save
end

private 
    def answer_params
        params.require(:answer).permit(:id, :description, :question_id)
    end
end
```

Here is `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :questions do
    resources :answers
  end
  resources :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "pages#welcome"
end
```

I got stuck on this error and I can't go any further so help would be greatly appreceated.

Comment: Try `<%= form_for [@question, @answer] do |f| %>`. Assuming that works, I'll write an answer with the explanation.

Comment: That looks like it could work, it's just that I have to do some other things now so when I come back I'll try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) you will get more idea.

For partials and forms become tricky. Note the square brackets:

```
<%= form_for  [@question, @answer] do |f| %>
```

Most importantly, if you want a URI, you may need something like this:

```
question_answer_path(@question, @answer)
```

Alternatively:

```
 [@question, @answer]
```

Comment: This is removing the error and that's why I put it as correct, but if you know why that form is not creating any record, just so I don't have to create another question.